# Why isn't JQuery creating a new div at each iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a container div for each image and its description at each iteration in my for loop, but JQuery is lumping all the image divs and description divs together into one container div, and that's messing up the whole layout.

I'm not sure why it's doing that, especially since I'm creating a new container div and appending to it within the for loop.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ZEZEME/wza7q3tn/4/

HTML

```
<div class=PgTwo></div>
```

JS

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    arr = data.data;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var articleInfo = arr[i];
        console.log(articleInfo);

        var imgURL = articleInfo["listingimage"]['url'];
        var title = articleInfo["title"];
        var desc = articleInfo["listingdescription"];

        if (imgURL != "") {

            var imgWrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var descDiv = document.createElement('div');

            imgDiv.id = 'imgDiv';
            imgWrapperDiv.id = 'imgWrapperDiv';
            descDiv.id = 'descDiv';

            descDiv.textContent = desc;
            var imgurlCSS = 'url("'+imgURL+'")';
            $(imgDiv).css({'background-image': imgurlCSS, 'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 'background-size': 'cover'});

            $(imgDiv).append($('<a href="" id=link >'+ title +'</a>').css('text-decoration', 'none'));
            $('#imgWrapperDiv').append(imgDiv);
            $('#imgWrapperDiv').append(descDiv);
            $('.PgTwo').append(imgWrapperDiv);
        }
     }
 });
```

Comment: I figured it out! Writing imgWrapperDiv.appendChild(imgDiv) instead of $('#imgWrapperDiv').append(imgDiv) fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You're only using one id in the for loop. So you're creating the wrapper div, then setting its id but every time it sets it to the same id as before. In the DOM only one wrapper div is present then.

Comment: Yes, but I do the same thing with the imgDiv and descDiv as well, yet those don't lump all into one div. They are created in separate divs, so why the difference?

Comment: The divs get created regardless of id, but when you try to append to an element by id it works by the one it finds. If you were trying to do something with those child divs you'd have problems too.
As a test, try appending the for loop counter to the ids

imgDiv.id = 'imgDiv_' + i;            
imgWrapperDiv.id = 'imgWrapperDiv_' + i;
descDiv.id = 'descDiv_' + i;

and see what it does